# XSD for one element out of a group of elements preceding another?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

The child elements of a parent element must have one element (out of a group) followed by another specific element.

```
<xsd:element name="elementContainer">
    <xsd:element name="element1">
    <xsd:element name="element2">
    <xsd:element name="element3">
    <xsd:element name="element4">
    <xsd:element name="element5">
    <xsd:element name="element6">
    <xsd:element name="proceedingElement">
</xsd:element>
```

I want to modify the XSD above so that there must be one element(1-6) followed by the proceeding element.

I've tried wrapping a choice around the elements 1 to 6 but that is not being picked up by validation.

```
<xsd:element name="elementContainer">
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="1">
        <xsd:element name="element1">
        <xsd:element name="element2">
        <xsd:element name="element3">
        <xsd:element name="element4">
        <xsd:element name="element5">
        <xsd:element name="element6">
    </xsd:choice>
    <xsd:element name="proceedingElement">
</xsd:element>
```

For the two following examples I would like the first to pass validation and the second to fail.

```
<elementContainer>
    <element2/>
    <proceedingElement/>
</elementContainer>

<elementContainer>
    <proceedingElement/>
</elementContainer>
```

The fact that there is a proceeding element could even be ignored if that helps, so just making sure that at least one element out of the six elements exists would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right basic idea regarding `xsd:choice`, but there are numerous problems with your XSD:

- `xsd:element` elements are not closed.
- `xsd:complexType` and `xsd:sequence` are missing.

With corrections for the above issues, and dropping default `xsd:choice/@minOccurs = 1`, this XSD,

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" > 
  <xsd:element name="elementContainer">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice>
          <xsd:element name="element1"/>
          <xsd:element name="element2"/>
          <xsd:element name="element3"/>
          <xsd:element name="element4"/>
          <xsd:element name="element5"/>
          <xsd:element name="element6"/>
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="proceedingElement"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

will require that there be one of `element1` through `element6` followed by one `proceedingElement`, as requested.

Comment: Thanks kjhughes, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, which might or might not be appropriate in your case, is to use substutition groups:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" > 
  <xsd:element name="elementContainer">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="abstractElement"/>
        <xsd:element name="proceedingElement"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="abstractElement" abstract="true"/>

  <xsd:element name="element1" substitutionGroup="abstractElement"/>
  <xsd:element name="element2" substitutionGroup="abstractElement"/>
  ... etc...
</xsd:schema>
```

The main advantage over xs:choice is that it is easier to add new elements to the substitution group: for example it can be done by a third party without modifying the original schema.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I might try this at a later time.